# Access PowerShell pipeline properties

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

Is there a way to expose the pipeline properties of the previous command in the output of the next command. Below will loop through each SQL Server and get databases. The output only gives me the database name but I am looking for a way to get the Server Name also in the output.

```
Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServer | Get-AzureSqlDatabase
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine [`Select-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx) with the [`-PipelineVariable` common parameter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847884.aspx) (`pv`) of a previous command:

```
Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServer -pv Server |Get-AzureSqlDatabase |Select-Object *,@{Label='ServerName';Expression={$Server.ServerName}}
```

Comment: Thank You @Mathias

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Foreach-Object` cmdlet for that:

```
Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServer | Foreach-Object { 
    $db = $_ | Get-AzureSqlDatabase 
    $db | Add-Member NoteProperty -name ServerName -value $_.ServerName
    $db
}
```